# Prevent appium desktop client force-stops the app

Tags: appium

Appium desktop client-server force-stop the app

Check the underlined code in the screenshot added

[image]

Comment: Seems like UiAutomator is crashing and due to that crash Appium force stops the app, check the "UiAutomator exited unexpectedly" message above. We'd need the whole logs of the crash to trace this problem further. You should also be more specific on what you're trying to achieve, and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can't track this down.

Answer (score -1):

It is something you can control from Appium Client code by providing relevant [Desired Capability](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Capabilities)

The one you're looking for is called [`autoLaunch` and defaults to `true`](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/), just set it to `false` and Appium will not stop/relaunch the application.

Example code:

```
//Set the Desired Capabilities
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
caps.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "your.app.package");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "your.app.package.YourAppActivity");
caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");
caps.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
caps.setCapability("autoLaunch","false"); // this one will tell Appium not to stop/start the application

AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```

Just make sure that your app is running or call [driver.launchApp()](https://static.javadoc.io/io.appium/java-client/7.2.0/io/appium/java_client/InteractsWithApps.html#launchApp--) function manually where required